# panel's different controls to list

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, panel

I have a `panel` with controls in them. Controls are `buttons` and `progressbars`. I would like to add only the buttons to a `list`, how can I do it?

```
foreach (Control item in panel1.Controls)
{
    //if (item.GetType() == typeof(ButtonControl))   //i tried this too...
    if ((item is ButtonControl) && (item.Tag.ToString() == "It's not important"))
    {                        
        panel1.BtnList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Here `ButtonControl` is my own Control, which is inherited from `Button` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LINQ you can do for `System.Windows.Forms.Button`

```
List<Button> buttonList = panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
```

If you want to check the Tag value as well then you can do

```
List<Button> buttonList = panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>()
                                         .Where(r => r.Tag.ToString() == "It's not important")
                                         .ToList();
```

EDIT: 
If `ButtonControl` is your own class then you can do:

```
 List<ButtonControl> buttonList = panel1.Controls.OfType<ButtonControl>().ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, its' great, thank you!

But i would like specify previously my list to Button Type... (Buttoncontrol is my own control, which is inherited from Buttons class...)

Comment: @user1807523, in that case you can use `OfType<ButtonControl>`

Comment: @user1807523, do you want to get the `ButtonControl` from the panel and add in a list of `Button` ?

Comment: @Habib Just curious to know, what wrong did the OP done in his/her code?

Comment: Otherwise me too... :)
The error was here:


    `panel1.BtnList.Add(item);`


And it's said, i would like to add a non ButtonControl type of button to ButtonControl list...

Comment: @Mr_Green, without seeing the `BtnList` definition, I am not really sure what was going on